# Why BasicComboBoxRenderer sets the text two times if the text does not exist or is empty with getPreferredSize()?

Tags: java, swing, java-17, renderer

While working on something related on using this class, i found this piece of code:

```
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    Dimension size;
    if (this.getText() == null || this.getText().isEmpty()) {
         setText( " " );
         size = super.getPreferredSize();
         setText( "" );
    } 
     else {
         size = super.getPreferredSize();
    }
    return size;
}
```

I do understand that this class is a JLabel and can use labels for rendering.
But why is being initialized (in case is not) during this getter?
Wouldn't make more sense on just doing it on the constructor?

Comment: Who know exactly why this code exists. You would have to ask the developer. It looks like if the text is empty the text is set to " " so a valid height (and minimum width) can be calculated.

Comment: Still doesn't make any sense. If we look up at the JLabel constructor is already initialized and his getPreferredSize() comes from JComponent, so by only using JLabel wouldn't make sense at all to set JLabel in case is not initialized.

Comment: *If we look up at the JLabel constructor* - the text is only set if you pass text to the constructor, otherwise is defaults to the empty string. The BasicComboBoxRenderer is created with a no parameter constructor.  Therefore, when it is created there will be no text associated with the renderer. The BasicComboBox renderer does NOT use the getPreferredSize() method from JComponent when no text exists. By temporarily setting the text the height and minimum width can be calculated.

Comment: Why do you care? Why are you looking at source code at this level? If you are trying to solve a problem then state your problem.

Comment: By calling super() you're actually calling JLabel constructor which internally initialises the text on BasicComboBoxRenderer.
I was pointing out why the overriding on the JComponent method (JLabel has it implemented by JComponent, not overriding it). And the renderer does use the getPreferredSize() from JComponent.

Comment: (1-) *which internally initialises the text on BasicComboBoxRenderer.* - as I stated above it initializes it to the empty string.  So the default getPreferredSize() method of JComponent won't calculate a reasonable size. *And the renderer does use the getPreferredSize() from JComponent.* - yes, but only after the default text has been manipulated. Sorry if that comment wasn't obvious, since the code obviously does invoke super.getPreferredSize().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By reading the [source code](https://developer.classpath.org/doc/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicComboBoxRenderer-source.html)

you can see a comment explaining such behavior:

```java
  76:   /**
  77:    * Returns preferredSize of the renderer
  78:    * 
  79:    * @return preferredSize of the renderer
  80:    */
  81:   public Dimension getPreferredSize()
  82:   {
  83:     if (this.getText() != null && ! this.getText().equals(""))
  84:       return super.getPreferredSize();
  85:     else
  86:       {
  87:         // If the combo box option's text is empty or null, it won't size
  88:         // properly (ie, it'll be way too short)... so we throw in a dummy
  89:         // space to trick the superclass's sizing methods.
  90:         String oldText = this.getText();
  91:         this.setText(" ");
  92:         Dimension d = super.getPreferredSize();
  93:         this.setText(oldText);
  94:         return d;
  95:       }
  96:   }
```

Comment: Just as I thought. It would be nice if all versions of the source code had the same comment: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.desktop/share/classes/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicComboBoxRenderer.java. I guess the code can change slightly from one release to another. Is there a way to tell which version is the most current?

Comment: @camickr the JDK sources never had this comment (checked for JDK 1.4.2 up to 21 and the master that you linked). It is only the [GNU classpath library](https://www.gnu.org/software/classpath/) that has this comment (but GNU classpath had its last release about 12 years ago.

Comment: @ThomasKläger, thanks, I will continue to use github for referencing source code.